# If a function $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic with $f'(z_0)\neq 0$, then f preserves angles at $z_0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is problem 2 of Chapter 8 from Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis that I've been looking at for a while.
[image: Chapter 8 Problem 2]

I'm not really sure where to even begin with this problem. I've been looking at the hint, but I don't understand how it is useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the article, they define the oriented angle $\alpha$ through:

$\cos\alpha = \dfrac{(z,w)}{|z||w|}$, $\sin\alpha = \dfrac{(z, -iw)}{|z||w|}$.

From it, you can extract the usual identity: $(z,w) = |z||w|\cos\alpha$.

---

Now, where does the hint come in?

To compare the angles between the pairs of curves $(\eta, \gamma)$ and $(f\circ\eta, f\circ\gamma)$, you want to compare angles between their respective tangent vectors.

So the question is, given a curve $\gamma$, what's the tangent vector of $f\circ\gamma$ at, say, time $t$? Given that $\gamma(t) = z_0$?

I'll leave it to you to do the calculation but the upshot is that this is going to be $f'(z_0) \gamma'(t)$.

(*If you are familiar with differential geometry language, this is saying that a function $f$ between spaces $X$ and $Y$ induces a linear map between their tangent vector spaces, given by the derivative.* But else, forget this comment)

So now, with this expression for the tangent vectors of $f\circ\gamma$ and $f\circ\eta$, you can compare their angles using the formula at the very start of my answer, and you'll see where the hint comes in useful! :)